# Web Api 2 IHttpRoute DataTokens

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

We are using WebApi 2 and I cannot find a way to set the DataTokens on the IHttpRoute created from configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute.

I downloaded the source code and it appears that the DataTokens are always set to null.  Is there any way to populate these as we want to use these values as we have come up with our own Areas implementation for Web Api that also allows us to version but not being able to set these values is causing us issues.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I continued looking through the source code and decided to add this extension however there must be a reason why the DataTokens was being nulled and I am worried I will cause issues elsewhere overloading in this way as it's so simple why wasn't this overload included originally.  Can anyone suggest why this is a bad idea?

```
public static IHttpRoute MapHttpRoute(this HttpRouteCollection routes, string name, string routeTemplate, object defaults, object constraints, HttpMessageHandler handler, object dataTokens)
{
  HttpRouteValueDictionary defaultsDictionary = new HttpRouteValueDictionary(defaults);
  HttpRouteValueDictionary constraintsDictionary = new HttpRouteValueDictionary(constraints);
  HttpRouteValueDictionary dataTokensDictionary = new HttpRouteValueDictionary(dataTokens);
  IHttpRoute route = routes.CreateRoute(routeTemplate, defaultsDictionary, constraintsDictionary, dataTokens: dataTokensDictionary, handler: handler);
  routes.Add(name, route);
  return route;
}
```